# Applying a formula when a row value changes

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a list of dates that have planned shipments. A specific date could have multiple shipments -- and the shipments are categorized as days early or late. Late denoted by a neg. sign.

For each unique date I am looking to compute the "avg days early", and the "avg days late".

I can manually do this for each date. For example on 7/4/2019 I found the average of the late days (which was 3) and the avg of the early days (4).

[image: Shipment data screenshot]

This works, however I'd like a way to automate this process, for each unique date in my spreadsheet.

Comment: You may be looking for [`AVERAGEIF`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AVERAGEIF-function-FAEC8E2E-0DEC-4308-AF69-F5576D8AC642)

Comment: I would do this in a pivot table to avoid repeating values. In the rows put the date field, in the columns put the "on time or late" column, and then in values put days late or early and set it to average rather the default sum or count

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. Show what you have tried and we can help solve it with you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Since you have two conditions, which are date and sign of value(+/-), you need to use `AVERAGEIFS` function.

```
=AVERAGEIFS(B:B,A:A,E3,B:B,">0")
```

[image]

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Please add some explanation as to how this solves the problem. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/23988172)